# Adding a history flag variable to panel data with possible auto-correlation

Tags: autocorrelation, panel-data

I have a pretty basic question.  A client has given me a data set with tens of thousands of subjects.  Each subject has from one to about ten separate records.  These records cover successive non-overlapping time periods of variable duration, up to one year.  There is a response variable, Y >= 0.  The client is interested in seeing, among other things, whether non-zero response within the previous three years has any predictive value / correlation with response in the current year.  We have decided to create a binary variable, A, with the value of 1 if Y > 0 for any record in the previous three years (for each individual subject), 0 otherwise.  Note that the oldest record for each subject will always have A = 0.  If most of my subjects had long historical trails, then I'd be willing to drop the first three years for each subject, and just do the analysis of Y versus A for all the records which have a full three year history.  However, for this data set, most individuals don't have three years of history, so many of the A variable values are partially truncated.  Of course, this could bias the analysis.  What is the best way to carry out this analysis?

Thanks!